# SDWebImage not displaying download images

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uibutton, sdwebimage

I used `SDWebImage` library for downloading remote images from server. But while im in EDGE connection it taking too much time and after downloading the `NSLog` values are displaying but images are not showing under `UIButton`

code:

```
int Width = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i<[productimg_array count]; i++ ) {

            NSLog(@"index %@", productimg_array[i]);

            imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 0, 72, 72)];

            Width = Width + 20+(i*74);

            [imgView1 setTag:i+1];

            [imgView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(dbClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            // [imgView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:i]]
            //   forState:UIControlStateNormal];

           [imgView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:i]]  forState:UIControlStateNormal completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

            NSLog(@"download images 1");
          }];

          [scrollview addSubview:imgView1];

        }

[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(Width,imgView1.frame.size.height+20)];
```

Comment: where do you declare imgView1? And how do you retain it? Because the variable name implies it is an imageView but you are assigning a UIButton to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there is an error or a timeout. Try this change and maybe we can find more:

```
[imgView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:i]]  forState:UIControlStateNormal completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"Callback Error:%@",error);
    }
    if(image){
        NSLog(@"Callback Image:%@",image);
    }
}];
```

Comment: when i use EDGE i got error:  Callback Error:Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)" UserInfo=0x20bde570 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://serverurl.net/projects/mobile/images/img.png}

Comment: does the URL have http:// infront of it or is that just stack overflow formatting things incorrectly?

Comment: this is sample url..I didn't use server url

Comment: If you do just have an error then you may want to increase the timeout for images downloaded via SDWebImage, How big are these images and from where are you downloading them?

Comment: In where? how? donwloading images from server with aspect ratio automatically

Comment: thanks to this hint, I have found "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection", which is the main reason why the image is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Heres something that worked for me, I keep the loop but I don't use it so it matches your code. I declared imgView1 to be a UIButton and I hardcoded a URL to a stackoverflow image. I recommend you check the type of imgView1 and the content of productimg_array

```
int Width = 0;
UIButton *imgView1;
for (int i = 0; i<1; i++ ) {


    imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 0, 72, 72)];

    Width = Width + 20+(i*74);

    [imgView1 setTag:i+1];

    [imgView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [imgView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=6"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

        NSLog(@"download images 1");
    }];

    [self.view addSubview:imgView1];

}
```

Comment: You didn't understand what im asking.  I declare  imgView1 in .h file and ARC enabled. productimg_array having all the images coming from remote images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method from `UIButton+WebCache.h`

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state;
```

Calling this is similar,

```
[imgView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This method will download the image and directly set it to the button.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I used above code. But when i was in EDGE connection it taking too much time to load, while im in wifi it load fast

Comment: @user2807197 That is something which cannot be controlled. Downloading performance will always be dependent on network speed. Sorry but there  is nothing you can do in the code to improve the network speed.